# oracle concatenate only if there are no matches

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

oracle concatenate only if there are no matches.

The goal is to add notes to comments only if there are no matches.

The following update statements adds notes to comments as it should , except that I am trying eliminate duplications.
Within the two tables, glass and notes, glass.id(pk) and notes.labelk(fk) are keyed.

Most of the comments and notes are unrelated.
A few comments include strings that are to be found in corresponding notes 
and those are the instances where I do not want to update the row.

I have tried variations to the NOT LIKE phrase with no luck.

Could someone point out what I need to change to not update rows where the comments contains strings found in the notes?

Any and all help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
UPDATE glass ll
set comments=(select ll.comments ||'-//-'||ln.notes
FROM notes ln
where ll.id = LN.LABELK
AND ('%ln.notes%') not like ('%ll.comments%')  
AND ROWNUM <2)
WHERE EXISTS (select ll.comments ||'-//-'||ln.notes
FROM notes ln
where ll.id = LN.LABELK
AND ('%ln.notes%') not like ('%ll.comments%'));
```

Comment: Using the INSTR function might be helpful to see if the notes are in the comments but it would use the entire notes string. I would think this would be tricky because you don't want words like 'a' and 'the' to cause it to match and not get updated?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You are correct.  the repeated portion will be alpha numeric and that is about as far as I can know about it... might be a sentence with 'a' or 'the'... or it might be a date.. or a series of numbers that don't relate to anything except each other.  That is why I was hoping the NOT LIKE would work.